# In DB2 :: is row level security is applicable on foreign key

Tags: db2

While giving row level access permissions on a table is that automatically applicable on foreign key and same while giving column level access .

I am not able to try yet . But while learning from manuals I have not see this explanation.

Comment: Could you give more details on your question? Do you mean that pk/fk checks are impacted by it (no)?

Comment: Hi , Yes you are correct. if I am putting row level permission on 1 table to user group. is it applicable to other tables where we have this as foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you call as "applicable".
Consider row permission as just an additional filter in your WHERE clause.
Look at the following example.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_P (P_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE TEST_C 
(
  P_ID INT NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT TEST_C_FK FOREIGN KEY (P_ID) REFERENCES TEST_P (P_ID)
);
INSERT INTO TEST_P VALUES 1;
INSERT INTO TEST_C VALUES 1;

-- Nobody can get any row from the parent table.
CREATE PERMISSION TEST_P1 ON TEST_P FOR ROWS WHERE FALSE ENFORCED FOR ALL ACCESS ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE TEST_P ACTIVATE ROW ACCESS CONTROL;

-- No rows are visible in the parent table
SELECT * FROM TEST_P;

-- But you can see the corresponding row in the child table 
-- and even get an "impossible" situation: a child row without a parent one
SELECT * FROM TEST_C 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TEST_P WHERE TEST_P.P_ID = TEST_C.P_ID);

|P_ID|
|----|
|1   |
```